# Unrecognized Option (vmArgs Java in VSCode)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx, testfx

I'm trying run package **org.testfx** in my **JavaFX** application, but i'm a facing  error *"JavaFX.graphics is not accessible"*. So I'm trying put **vmArgs** in **VsCode tests** to exports javafx.graphics, but not sucessfuly, one help?

[image: The new error: Unrecognized option: --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED]

My Code:

```
"java.test.config":
        {
            "name": "testConfig",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "vmArgs": ["--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED"]
        }
```

Comment: See the documentation on using [JavaFX plus VSCode](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  You also want to use TestFX, which will be additional work.  But make sure you can at least run the basic HelloWorld app from the linked tutorial in your environment.

Comment: @jewelsea I can run the JavaFX in VSCode, my application run perfectly, but my problem is, I want to make a test automatized with **org.testfx**, for test all process my application. My problem: **org.testfx** need to access **javafx.graphics**, but my application is modular, and cannot be access in **javafx.graphics**.                                                       My Questions: How can i put **vmArgs** `"--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED"` for tests.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. My thought is that you should check your grammar and please post your error as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I resolved the problem, but not the way I expected.

## Resolution

I removed the module-info.java to have no problem with access modules, apparently have just this option, so I have other problem, but nothing that interrupts my application.

the problem: `WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @4f10c7de'`.

I resolved this with put vmArgs in launch.json on vscode:

> `"--module-path \"location-javafx\\lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml"`.

### What I wanted?

I want to make a test automatized with **org.testfx**, for test all process my application and minimize bugs.

To persons who have this problem, if that way don't working for you, try these links:

#### StackOverflow

- [JavaFX WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854139/javafx-warning-unsupported-javafx-configuration-classes-were-loaded-from-unna)
- [JavaFX project wrapped with Launch4j VM arguments path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873306/javafx-project-wrapped-with-launch4j-vm-arguments-path)
- [IllegalAccessError when trying to use TestFX caused by module-info.java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910148/illegalaccesserror-when-trying-to-use-testfx-caused-by-module-info-java-file)

#### VSCode's site and GitHub

- [VSCode java Testing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing)
- [OpenJFX 11 compatibility issue](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/638)

If anyone can find another answer, please share with me, please.